# Как отправлять данные другому пользователю через WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Во всех примерах в интернете разрабатывается чат подобный стриму где данные отправляются всем ползователям подряд, но мне надо соединить два клиента и делиться данными между ними.

Сервер на Node js

С веб сокетами работаю впервые. Концепт не очень понятен... пожалуйста разъясните как устроена архитектура такого рода приложений. Спасибо

Comment: Каждое соединение однозначно идентифицируется и может получать сообщения... Нужно "сообщать" серверу "кому именно адресовано" твое сообщение.

Comment: Вот тут есть пример чата -  https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket  Но отправляет всем. Если "заставить", подключенного первый раз, указать свой уникальный ник - его можно запомнить вместе с его идентификацией подключения. В его сообщениях нужно будет указывать его ник. Т.о. другие смогут обращаться к нему по нику в своих сообщениях. И сервер должен такие сообщения отсылать только адресатам, которых он будет по тем никам идентифицировать...

Comment: Как вы указываете я собирал все подключения в один объект и в качестве ключа на каждое подключение брал ник клиента. Не знаю наверно сервер логает, самому клиенту отправлять сообщения сокет умеет, но с подключениями с других вкладок у него не получается

Comment: Далее уже нужно переходить на вполне конкретные вопросы и показывать тестовые примеры...